# Strange issue with using Java ProcessBuilder on Windows 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: windows, scala, process, builder

I've delopped some Scala code to control the lifecycle of MySQL server. The code runs fine on Windows XP, but fails under Windows 2008 R2 standard with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql" (in directory ".\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
        at com.quantel.dbcontroller.ProcessExecutor$.run(dbcontroller.scala:63)
        at com.quantel.dbcontroller.MySQL$User.execSQL(dbcontroller.scala:90)
        at com.quantel.dbcontroller.MySQL.isRunning(dbcontroller.scala:172)
        at com.quantel.dbcontroller.MySQL.start(dbcontroller.scala:126)
        at com.quantel.dbcontroller.Launch$.main(dbcontroller.scala:195)
        at com.quantel.dbcontroller.Launch.main(dbcontroller.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
        ... 6 more
```

I am a bit baffled as to why this works fine on XP but not on Windows 2008 R2. Has anyone experience something similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my mistake. I had forgotten to prefix the command to execute with cmd /c. Strangely, Windows XP does not complain about the omission of cmd /c while Windows 2008 does.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like anything specific to Scala, There's something else changed when you upgraded windows (I'm assuming this was an upgrade)

Try double-checking that your system path is okay, that you're launching the program from the correct location, etc.